# Wagtail serve different language on home page

Tags: django, url, internationalization, multilingual, wagtail

From documentation:
Users are forwarded to their preferred version, based on browser language, when they first visit the site.

Question:
Is it possible users to be forwarded not based on browser language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can give the user a cookie that will set the language of the site for the duration of  the cookie age.

If you choose to redirect using browser language or any other way, there should still be some default fallback language.

You can have a look at [wagtail multilingual site documentation.](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12/advanced_topics/i18n/duplicate_tree.html?highlight=multilingual#creating-a-multilingual-site-by-duplicating-the-page-tree)

Here is some [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions) documentation for setting the session.